# Which are the preinstalled PowerShell modules and why a cmdlet could be missing in a machine?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

During the installation process of our software we use a batch file that replaces some text in some configuration files depending on user's input. The batch file basically calls a PowerShell command to do so:

```
REM %1 - file name e.g. file.txt
REM %2 - variable placeholder text e.g. {%placeholder%}
REM %3 - text to replace variable placeholder e.g. BLAH
powershell -Command "(gc %1) -replace '%2', '%3' | Out-File -encoding UTF8 %1" || echo ErrorLevel %errorlevel% > injection-bat.err
```

Some customers report that the batch file is failing. After some research on the failing machines we're able to see that PowerShell does not recognize the "Get-Content" (gc) cmdlet:

`The term 'Get-Content' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

By taking a look on the installed PowerShell modules in the failing machine I was able to see that the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` module is not present. However, on all machines we've tested, the module is there (even in a clean fresh Windows installation).

Since I could not find a clear answer on that, I ask it here ...

Why so a basic module (`Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`) is not present in a Windows machine? Is there a list of "preinstalled" modules in Windows we can assure are always there? Would it be better to somehow install/import those modules using the batch file before using them just to be on the safe side? If this module is preinstalled with Windows, is there a reason why the module could be removed from the machine?

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**

I was able to find the PS version installed -> 5.1

The module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` is not in the list of available modules (`Get-Module -ListAvailable`).

**UPDATE 2:**

Here I answer the questions from @leeharvey1:

*Does `$Env:PSModulePath` list `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`?*

Yes

```
C:\Users\MAN Langenhagen\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
```

*Does `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1` exist?*

Yes

*Is `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll` present in your `%PATH%` (eg, `$env:Path -split ';' | % { dir "$_\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll" -ea silentlycontinue }`)?*

I was not able to execute the command. But a Windows search showed 4 matches of the dll in:

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35
C:\Windows\WinSxS\msil_microsoft.powershell.commands.management_31bf3856ad364e35_1.0.0.0_none_9fba00a194c2da2a
C:\Windows\WinSxS\msil_microsoft.powershell.commands.management_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_fcfa075fee21fc1f
```

However, these locations seem not to be part of the PATH (unless recursive).

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

*Is a .NET Framework 4 version installed (eg, `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::FrameworkDescription`)?*

That command returned nothing, however the call `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]` returned:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    RuntimeInformation                       System.Object
```

Comment: Which PowerShell version are they running? If it's prior to 3.0, modules don't load automatically when needed: [Beginning in PowerShell 3.0, PowerShell imports modules automatically the first time that you run any command in an installed module.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules)

Comment: @Dabombber Windows 10 is a prerequisite to install our software. AFAIK Windows 10 comes with Windows PowerShell 5.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/install/windows-powershell-system-requirements?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: The system does know that `gc` is the alias of `Get-Content` but doesn't load the module? sound strange...

Comment: Just some things to check... Does `$Env:PSModulePath` list `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`?  Does `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1` exist?  Is `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll` present in your `%PATH%` (eg, `$env:Path -split ';' | % { dir "$_\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll" -ea silentlycontinue }`)?  Is a .NET Framework 4 version installed (eg, `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::FrameworkDescription`)?

Comment: @leeharvey1 I've answered your questions in the update